# select statement multi tables with a new colums whose value dependson other in different table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table containing a column referencing other rows in other tables or not.
For example:
- the table Table_Cart has a column product as a number
- if the product is a fruit then it points to a row in table Table_Fruit,
- if the product is a vegetable then it points to a row in table Table_Vegetable
- if none of the above we can leave the value as empty

I need to generate an output like stating for each product if it's "fruit"/"vegetable"/empty
so it should look like

```
| product | category |
| 1111111 | fruit    |
| 2222222 | vegetable|
| 1111113 | fruit    |
| 4444444 |          |
```

Today the sql I wrote is

```
select T1.product, T2.category
from Table_Cart T1 left join
     (select product, "fruit" as "category" from Table_fruit
      union
      select product, "vegetable" as "category" from Table_vegetable
     ) T2
     on T1.product = T2.product
```

Is there any better way to write this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't yet understand. The cart table contains a product ID. But there exists no product table. Instead you have a fruit table and a vegetable table and maybe others. The cart's product ID references either a row in the fruit table or one in the vegetable table or none of the two. You see it guaranteed that no ID exists in both, the fruit table and in the vegetable table, at the same time. Is this correct?

Comment: This looks to be a very unfortunate data model. Is there some severe reason to have separate tables per product kind rather than one common product table?

Comment: As to your query: 1. The quotes are incorrect, as already mentioned in Tejash's answer. 2. Don't use `UNION` when you actually only want `UNION ALL`. `UNION` has the additional task of looking for duplicates and removing them. 3. Make it a habit to use mnemonic alias names. `T1` and `T2` make a query less readable, then, say, `c` or `cart` for `table_cart` and `p` or `prod` for the unioned product tables would.

Comment: thanks for the comments and regarding the datamodel, I have no answer why it was designed this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using sub-query and do direct `LEFT JOIN` as following:

```
 SELECT
     T.PRODUCT,
     CASE
         WHEN TF.PRODUCT IS NOT NULL THEN 'fruit'
         WHEN TV.PRODUCT IS NOT NULL THEN 'vegetable'
     END AS CATEGORY
 FROM
     TABLE_CART T
     LEFT JOIN TABLE_FRUIT TF ON ( T.PRODUCT = TF.PRODUCT )
     LEFT JOIN TABLE_VEGETABLE TV ON ( T.PRODUCT = TV.PRODUCT )
```

Also, Please note that the `"` (double quotes) for the constant value of the column (`"fruit", "vegetable"`) is not correct, It should be wrapped in the `'` (single quotes) like (`'fruit', 'vegetable'`)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments